# Clone and continue with what was happening on previous div

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, append

I am doing a post call and want to clone the div that depicts the status to on to another div.

But when I do the clone, what happens is that that it copies what is exactly on the previous element and does not continue with the **change status** that I set up in the previous div.

My code:

```
let arr = ['Hermione', 'Ron', 'Harry']

arr.forEach(d=>{
    $('#the_table>tbody').append(` 
                <tr id='tr_${d}'>
                    <td'>${d}</td>
                    <td><i id='change_${d}' class='no'></i></td>
                </tr>
            `);
});

const myfunc = () => {
$.post(api, json_object,
    function(data, status) {
        if (data.value === 'started') {
        setTimeout(myfunc, 5000);
    } else {
        $(`#change_${d}`).removeClass('no').addClass('yes');
        }
}, 'json');
            }
myfunc();
```

I am then cloning that table to another div elsewhere on the page.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('#show_clone').show();
  $('#the_table').clone().appendTo('#show_clone');
});
```

When I do this clone, the status stops changing on the cloned div.

How do I make it continue the status change process.

Comment: Probably because the clone has same id as orignal ... and ID's must be unique in a page

Comment: @charlietfl, thank you for the sanity check. That is correct